# Remove "\" from strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having some trouble removing slashes in Javascript.

I've got some HTML coming through via JSON and need to get rid of the escaping slashes.

Here's what I have now, but it doesn't seem to work - at all...

```
obj.embed_code = obj.embed_code.replace(/\\/g, '');
```

The HTML inside that object is an embed iframe from YouTube, but since it's got the escaped quotes I just end up with an iframe that's got a 404 page in it.

What would be the correct way to do this?

Here's an example of what the output looks like...

```
<iframe width=\\\"420\\\" height=\\\"315\\\" src=\\\"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/MD61itbPNEY\\\" frameborder=\\\"0\\\" allowfullscreen><\/iframe>
```

In addition, here's the page where the JSON is being pulled from so you can see what it looks like raw...

http://bit.ly/UxuvfL

Comment: why a regex for a simple replacement? `x = str.replace('\\')`.

Comment: @MarcB, using a string replacement will only replace the first instance, that's what the `g` flag is for on the RegExp.

Comment: Just for reference: `'cbc'.replace('c', 'a');` returns `'abc'`, not `'aba'` as would be expected by someone new to JS.

Comment: That code should work as-is. The problem is probably elsewhere. Please create a [reduced test case using jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) (assuming the intended result is to remove ``\`` characters).

Comment: How does `obj.embed_code` look like? Did you decode the JSON? I corrected my answer to remove escaping slashes but I can only guess what the problem is.

Comment: Just added an example of what the output looks like, and it's a bit different than I thought it was. But above is what the output actually is straight from the file I pull the JSON from.

Comment: Ok, I adapted my answer to your string. That should work. But I would wonder where all the slashes came from...

Comment: From what I can gather, one comes from when I insert into mysql, (although it should be removed when pulled...) another when JSON gets encoded, but there's one more than I can't really account for. I'm not really sure.

Comment: Ok, that explains it. First escape: `" => \"`, Second escape: `\ " => \\ \"`. You should decode the JSON using `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Just linked to the raw JSON, if that helps. So far I'm not seeing anything working...

Specifically, the areas I need this to work on are embed_code and call_to_action.

Comment: Your JSON is valid. My answer below should clean it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is truly JSON then the *correct* way would be to use a JSON parser, as there's more to JSON parsing than simply removing backslashes.  Given something like

```
{"content":"<p>CleverStuff\u2122<\/p>"}
```

`JSON.parse(theData).content` would give you

```
<p>CleverStuff™</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`obj.embed_code = obj.embed_code.replace(/\\\//g, "/");`

It matches `\/` so you don't accidentally remove unescaped instances of `/`

Answer (score -1):

Your JSON is valid, i checked with [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/).

This should clean embed_code up:

```
obj.embed_code = obj.embed_code.replace(/\\\\\\"/g, '"').replace(/\\\//g, "/");
```

Works fine for me:

```
> var a = "width=\\\\\\\"420 src=\\\\\\\"http:\\/\\/www"
"width=\\\"420 src=\\\"http:\/\/www"
> a.replace(/\\\\\\"/g, '"').replace(/\\\//g, "/")
"width="420 src="http://wwww"
```

But I would recommend this:

```
$.getJSON('http://webiwave.com/includes/checkForButton.php?id=922', function (data){
    console.log(data.embed_code.replace(/\\\"/g, '"') ) 
});
```

If I run this on your webpage I get clean html:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/MD61itbPNEY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I edit my answer a few times, so don't be scared by the old down votes.